# Display name one by one using JSON and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

How to display name one by one using ajax. It seem that my FOR looping is not working to push name one by one. Is there any step that i miss? Can someone point me to where/what i did wrong.

```
    var names = [];
    var profiles = {};

    var restURL = "fetch.php";

    function refresh() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url:restURL,
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                for (var k in result) {                 
                    var name = result[k].name;                      
                    if (!profiles.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                        names.push(name);
                        profiles[name] = result[k];
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }


    var namei = -1;

    function nextName() {
        namei++;
        if (namei > names.length - 1) {
            namei = Math.max(1, names.length - 10) - 1;
        }
        console.log(namei + '/' + names.length);
        $('.texts li:first', '.jumbotron #atname').text(profiles[names[namei]].name);
        $('.texts li:first', '.jumbotron #atdiv').text(profiles[names[namei]].division);
        $('.jumbotron .tlt').textillate('start');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.jumbotron .tlt').textillate('out');
        }, 5000);
    }
```

fecth.php

```
$i=1;
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs) ) {
$response['result'][] = array(
    'staffno' => $row['g_idm'],     
    'name' => $row['g_name'],       
    'division' => $row['g_div']     
);
$i++;
} 
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Where do you call `nextName()` and where do you call `refresh()` ? You do know you need to process after the `for (var k in result) {` loop and nowhere else?

Comment: Have you verified the script sends the request?  Does PHP receive this request and pass back info?  Do you know where this is failing?

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Code seems to either be incomplete or excessive - it's not clear how either of the two JS functions are called and when. Also, you describe vaguely something "not working"...what do you mean exactly? What happens? What did you expect to happen? What was the input data? What should be the output? What debugging have you done - check that your program flow goes where you think it should, check any errors you get etc etc. All this you can do before posting the question - you might even find the answer yourself. "Not working" is a user's description of the problem, not a programmer's.